# ASP.NET Core Identity adding Custom selectlist item

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a question about my new ASP.NET Core application. I want to add a user using Microsoft Identity, but it must be customizable.

For example, if anyone will record on my registration page, they must select a department type from a selectlist. If anyone has an idea and code samples, please share these with me.

Thanks!

Comment: There are several types of Microsoft Identity, Could you specify the type you are using? Or how did you add the identity platform?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft ASP .Net Core Identity as Type and I had to be customize Registration side of my User Management System. .But actually  Problem has been solved.Thanks your help!